# Volume of solid of revolution about x-axis via Disks

Tags: calculus, volume, absolute-value

Good morning, I am attempting to solve the following problem from the back of my book, but am struggling with the correct approach to setup as I cannot find Youtube videos with examples of how to work with curves involving absolute values.

The volume of the region bounded by $y = |x − 3|$ and $y = 3$ revolved about the
$x$-axis.

What I have so far:

Attempting to approach this via disk method: $\pi$ * [integral from b to a of $y_1^2 - y_2^2]$

The absolute value however throws me off. Does this mean I need to consider both $x+3$ and $x-3$?

Any guidance on how to setup this integral would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
J

Comment: For the absolute value you need to consider the domain: y=|x-3| has the value x-3 if x $\geq$ 3 and otherwise y has the value -(x-3)=3-x

Comment: This clears it up for me. Thank you @gd1035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region revolved looks like this:

```
 ^y
 |
3#######
 |#####
 | ###
 o--#--->x
    3
```

Consider each side of the absolute value separately. For this region's left half with $0\le x\le3$, the lower bound is $y=3-x$ and the upper bound is $y=3$. For the right half with $3\le x\le6$, the lower bound changes to $y=x-3$.

The integrals can then be set up for the disc method. I show the left half's integral below; the right half is for you to complete, as well as the evaluation.
$$\pi\int_0^3(3^2-(3-x)^2)\,dx$$

Comment: Your illustration helps incredibly. Thank you very much!

Comment: To be clear then, the right region's integral would be: π  * [integral from b to a of (3)^2−(x-3)^2 dx], correct? I would then proceed to add the two integrals? This is how I understand it, and would be grateful for a confirmation of thought process.

Comment: @jackbenimbo $a=3$ and $b=6$ are the limits of the second integral, yes, while you do add the two parts together, yes.

Comment: Fully clear - thanks!